# minecraft beta question

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

i have a question if i use beta on my existing world and start playing with the beta , then the realse daate for the beta upate actually gets here what happens to your world ? since youve been playing in beta mode when you switch back to normal minecraft do you lose your world of new things you did in beta mode please respond for me i have been looking for this answer all over the internet im iffy to use beta on my world

Comment: I'm not sure if what you asked is what you intended to ask. Minecraft beta has ended some 10 years ago. Did you mean snapshots maybe?

Answer (score 0):

If you start playing with the beta- or any older version- of Minecraft, and update it to a newer version, your world is pretty much fine. If you go to unexplored chunks in the updated version in the same world, the only potential issue is that you might see a noticeable wall of terrain generation differences depending on the versions you jump to and from. You'll also notice other differences between the versions, but beside that, there aren't any real issues. Now days (in Java edition at least) you'll get this nice message to warn you.[image: Here's an example that I have.]